# docker mount data from container to host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I created own Dockerfile, during building I inserted to /opt/wilfly/log my log4j.xml.
Now I need create volume /mnt/data/logs/application:/opt/wildfly/log

I run command
 sudo docker run --name=myapp -v /mnt/data/logs/application:/opt/wildfly/log -d -i -t application

But when I look in docker container, folder /opt/wilfly/log is empty. In this folder should by log4j.xml.

Thank you.

Comment: At the very least you should decide if you want to use `/opt/wilfly/log` (1st and 4th occurrence in your question) or `/opt/wildfly/log` (2nd and 3rd). Then log into the container `docker exec -it {containerId} sh`, create a file under your desired directory and check if you can see it on the host. If yes, you application is simply not creating a log, if not, you are probably mounting/looking in a wrong place.

Comment: Having seen the answers, I will dare to suggest that you should not be mounting log configuration from host to container. It should be deployed as an integral part of the container. What you should be mounting is the directory for log outputs to preserve them after container stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should move it into another directory.

For example move **log4j.xml** to */opt/wilfly/* and set logging path to */opt/wilfly/log*.

When you run the container, log4j.xml will not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

When you mount the data, the folder from your host "override" your mounted folder within the container.

Thus, there are some options you can do:

1. copy the `log4j.xml` into your local `/mnt/data/logs/application` folder and run the container as you did.
2. remove the `-v /mnt/data/logs/application:/opt/wildfly/log` and use the original `log4j.xml` that you were added during the image build.

Please note that you can also mount only the file if you like (rather than the entire floder): `-v /mnt/data/logs/application/log4j.xml:/opt/wildfly/log/log4j.xml` but it won't change the behavior - the file from your host will be mounted into the container and not in the opposite direction.

Comment: Man the question is confusing... I did not even realise that the OP wanted to copy a logger config file from host to container, which is neither smart nor really clear :)